# DB4o database DatabaseFileLockedException

Tags: database, parallel-processing, db4o, locked

I would like to access the same db file from different programs in parallel. All programs are running on the same VM. Here is the code I use:

```
private ObjectContainer db;

public DatabaseManager(String dbName) {
    ObjectServer server = Db4oClientServer.openServer(Db4oClientServer
            .newServerConfiguration(), dbName, 0);
    try {
         db = server.openClient();

        // Do something with this client, or open more clients

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run the second program I get DatabaseFileLockedException. How to use this db in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one db4o instance can access the database file at the same time. If you try to reopen it while a object container has it open you will get this DatabaseFileLockedException.

Within the same JVM instance you can open new [session containers like](http://community.versant.com/documentation/Reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/advanced_topics/session_containers.htm) this:

```
 ObjectContainer rootContainer = // the one you've opened the file with
 ObjectContainer session = rootContainer.ext().openSession()
```

With your code you also can use the .openClient() method to do the same. However you actually don't need the client server stuff as long as you're in the same JVM instance. You can use the stuff above with a regular embedded object container.

In case you need to access the same database from multiple databases, then you need a full blown [client-server setup](http://community.versant.com/documentation/Reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/client-server.htm).